# Move from ng2-select and use ngx-bootstrap's typeahead like a select

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I was using `ng2-select` component but its last commit was in January and it lacks async items support. The owner suggested that most of its features are being integrated into `ngx-bootstrap/typeahead` component, but it requires the user to start typing some letter to find the filtered items.

Is it possible to make it open the complete list of items when it gets focused, just like ng2-select does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `[typeaheadMinLength]` option to 0, after this dropdown with options will be opened on click.

A little demo https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#reactive-forms